# How can I detect chrome installation path in registry?

Tags: google-chrome, nsis

I want to set out path installation by detecting chrome path from registry.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The path is stored in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome
```

and you can use [ReadRegStr](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/ReadRegStr.md) to query it

Comment: I can't find that key on my computer even though I have Chrome installed. I suspect this answer might be out of date now.